# highstock. Can I add one line of tooltip when the point is in the area of plotbands?

Tags: tooltip, highcharts

I have a line and several plotbands in a stockchart.

First I wanna show the plotband's name as it's label, but when the timerange is "all", then the plotband's width is so short, and the label overlap on each other.

So I wannt show the plotband's name in the point's tooltip, such as:

```
Tooltip's head
* plotband's name
* lineName: xxx
```

When the point is not in a plotbands, then the "plotband's name " shouldn't be shown.

Can I? or is there any other method to show the plotband's name properly, without overlap?

Comment: I have already found that I can use "this.series..options.xAxis[0].plotBands" in pointFormatter, then I can judge whether current point is in the plotBand or not.

But, if I show the plotbands info in "pointFormatter", then every series will add the same plotbands info, it is useless.

I wanna to add plotbands info in headerFormat, but it is a text, not a js function, what should I do? Is there a similar "headerFormatter"? I cannot find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by myself，“formatter” can be used，and we can get the plotbands info by this.series.options.xAxis[0].plotBands, then we can judge whether the point is in current bands.